# autofac nuget update changes IAutofacActionFilter implementation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have an asp.net web api2 project where I needed to add certain P3P values in response headers and used  ActionFilterAttribute implementations which worked..

In my development environment I tried implementing Autofac 3.5.2 and its web api integration module 3.4.

The documentation spoke of using IAutofacActionFilter implementations and I tried using them.

The following was the code..

```
public void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("P3P", 
            "CP=\\\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\\\"");
}

public void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{    
}
```

And in my Dependencies.config I added..

```
builder.Register(c => new myActionFilter())
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<DefaultController>(c => c.myaction(default(myclass)))
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

Because myaction was async.., c.myaction(default(myclass)) threw warning "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."

The application seemed to work but as I was unable to get rid of the warning, I decided not to implement Autofac at that point in time.

Recently, we got a mandate of using Autofac in the project and today when I opened the application and updated the nuget packages, I found that Autofac had updated to ver 4.1.0 and web api integration module to 4.0.0.

Now since Autofac 4.0.0, The Autofac filter interfaces now use Task/async based method signatures rather than synchronous signatures.

Unfortunately Autofac documentation (http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html) still shows the old style of code and has not updated.

I would sincerely appreciate if someone who is aware of the new style could let me know how to change the old code to new.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your `myActionFilter` class to the following:

```
public Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("P3P",
            "CP=\\\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\\\"");

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

public Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```